# The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to POST data using a REST API. The app used to run flawlessly, but now that I've added code to perform the POST, I'm getting a new error. Would anyone be able to help explain what's going wrong and suggest an alternative that would let me complete the POST request successfully?

Here's the error I get when I try to build the app with the linker enabled in the Release configuration:

```
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.StandardOleMarshalObject' (defined in 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089') from 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' could not be resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Runtime.InteropServices.StandardOleMarshalObject
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.Android.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() GimcoIOT.Andriod
```

Comment: There are no errors in my post code.when doing it in release mode im getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have added a reference to a desktop .NET assembly in your Xamarin.Android app.  The `System.Windows.Forms` namespace is not available in the Xamarin.Android profile.  (Even if the app *builds* successfully when you disable linking, it will in theory still fail at *run time* any time it tries to run code that references the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.)

To solve this problem, you will want to remove the reference to the desktop .NET assembly from your Xamarin.Android project and ensure that all of your other referenced assemblies are compiled either against the Xamarin.Android profile or a supported PCL profile.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/assemblies/):

> Xamarin.Android is *not* ABI compatible with existing assemblies compiled for a different profile. You *must* recompile your source code to generate assemblies targeting the Xamarin.Android profile (just as you need to recompile source code to target Silverlight and .NET 3.5 separately).

(Portable Class Libraries are the special exception to this rule.)

---

If you are currently using a type from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace to perform the POST request, then you will need to switch to a different type.  For example, one of the `PostAsync()` methods from [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) might work nicely.